# Access lambda.runtime.Context from beans in quarkus aws-lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dependency-injection, quarkus

In my quarkus-amazon-lambda application I would like to access *com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context* as a injectable bean. For example to get AwsRequestId or remaining time.

Right now I'm doing it this way:

```
public interface ContextHolder {
    Context getContext();
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class Lambda implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, SQSBatchResponse> {

    private volatile Context context;

    @Override
    public SQSBatchResponse handleRequest(SQSEvent input, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        ...
    }

    @ApplicationScoped
    @Produces
    public ContextHolder context() {
        return () -> context;
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class AnyOtherBean {
    @Inject
    private ContextHolder contextHolder;
}
```

Not sure that's correct and the best way of doing this.

A bit shorter version:
implement ContextHolder in Lambda, and return context reference directly:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class LambdaEntryPoint implements ContextHolder, RequestHandler<SQSEvent, SQSBatchResponse> {

    private volatile Context context;

    @Override
    public SQSBatchResponse handleRequest(SQSEvent input, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
```

Comment: If I were you, I would look at how Quarkus handles as a similar case in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/3.0.0.CR1/extensions/amazon-lambda-http/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/amazon/lambda/http/AwsHttpContextProducers.java#L25